# Built in audit tracking database

Tags: audit

I remember reading a blog post last year about a database with built in audit tracking, being able to get a version of any table at a point in time without any custom work needing to be done. Maybe it was RDS announcing support for that specific type of db. I can’t for the life of me remember. Anyone able to remind me what it was?

Comment: [Temporal tables](https://www.google.com/search?q=temporal+tables)?

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @mustaccio for pointing me in the right direction, https://aws.amazon.com/timestream/

Comment: Uhm, no. A time series database is not something that is "able to get a version of any table at a point in time without any custom work".